# Android Canvas is saving previous state when object is moving

Tags: java, android, canvas

Here's my problem:

When rendering an object which has speed (ie it's moving), the last frame of the object is also drawn, meaning that instead of a nice moving animation, I end up with the object drawn multiple times across its movement path.

Here is my render method (in the game loop):

```
private void render() {
    //if the surface is NOT valid, exit rendering
    if (!surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
        return;
    }
    //lock the canvas
    canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
    //draw all game objects to canvas (only 1 object atm)
    wizard.render(canvas);
    //unlock and post the canvas
    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
```

and the wizard render:

```
public void render(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(spriteSheet, position.x, position.y, null);
}
```

As far as I know, between each unlock and lock of the surface, its contents are not preserved, meaning that it is completely redrawn each time the render function is called:

"The content of the Surface is never preserved between unlockCanvas() and lockCanvas(), for this reason, every pixel within the Surface area must be written." ~ taken from the documentation

So why isn't this happening? Why is the canvas not being re-drawn and instead is preserving all of the wizard's frames?

Thanks in advance! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
public void render(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(spriteSheet, position.x, position.y, null);
    invalidate();
}
```

and see what happens.

Comment: This does not work. Wizard is not a view, it is a custom Class I created, therefore there is no invalidate method...